# Empty data result ajax with codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve data from my controller function but this very simple example fails and sends me nothing back. The ajax function is successfully executed but the data is empty.

```
    function company_select() {
    var data;
    var username = $('[name="username"]').val();
    var url = base_url+'/admin/user/get_companies2';
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown) }  
    });
}
```

codeigniter function

```
public function get_companies2(){

    echo 'test';
}
```

Comment: Did you set route setup ..?

Comment: where you defined base_url ?

Comment: what do you have when you console.log(data) in your ajax success callback?

Comment: The url is valid. He doesn't throw an error also. I already used multiple ajax calls which work well. But with an other controller.

Comment: console.log(data) is empty.

Comment: There wont be any error if the controller admin has a method called user... the get_companies2() will not be getting called unless the user method is handling the get_companies2 parameter to call that method name.

Comment: didn't get in error

Comment: base_url is defined in the js file. But the url is correct.

Comment: But that also depends upon any routes you may have configured to handle it.

Comment: TimBrownlaw -> I get an error when I call an undefined function. What you mean by handling the get_companies2 parameter? It is a function in the controller?

Comment: Ok as you have not shown us your admin controller, does the admin  controller have a method called user?

Comment: Tim, the controller is user, admin is a folder. The user controller has a method called get_companies2

Comment: Ok so a better test is to actually put that URL direct into your Browser. So when you do you should see it echo test. That's a first check.

Comment: We've got a first indication that something is wrong. As I'm executing this on my login page. When I call this function, I get redirected to the login page as i'm not loggedin yet

Comment: Problem solved. On login check I added the url to my controller method to be excluded from the login check:          //login check
        $exception_uris = array('admin/user/login', 'admin/user/logout', 'admin/user/get_companies');
        if (in_array(uri_string(), $exception_uris) == FALSE) {
            if ($this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE) {
                redirect('admin/user/login');
            }
        }

Comment: shouldn't your base url be like this `<?= base_url() ?>`. its codeigniter's function and you are appending a js variable

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use "data" instead of "dataType" Or Passed your require variables one by one as  into curli braces of data (as data:{variable1:})

function company_select(){

```
var data;
var username = $('[name="username"]').val();
var url = base_url+'/admin/user/get_companies2';
alert(url);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {username :username},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown) }  
});
```

}